# Null Conditional Operator throws a Null Reference for Event

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

As i understand it the null conditional operator (?.) checks for null before running the next bit of code but in this code:

```
public delegate void EventArgs(object Sender, PlayerPage Page);
public event EventArgs PageChanged;
private PlayerPage _CurrentPage = PlayerPage.NoPage;
public PlayerPage CurrentPage
{
    get { return _CurrentPage; }
    set { _CurrentPage = value; PropertyChangedFire(); this?.PageChanged(this,value); }
}
```

But
    this?.PageChanged(this,value);
throws a null refrence exception

Edit:

Ohh... how dumb of me :)
changed to PageChanged?.Invoke();
Thanks for the quick response

Comment: `this` clearly isn't null.  But your `PageChanged` event certainly still could be if you have no subscribers.

Comment: Are you try to do coalescing, which is ??

Comment: Are you trying to check if `PageChanged` is null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it's not what you think?

The `?.` checks `this` for null *). Actually, it's hard for `this` to be null.

`public event EventArgs PageChanged;` is an **event**. When there are no handlers attached, the event's "value" is null. In this moment, calling `this?.PageChanged(this,value);` would throw. I'm pretty sure that's the case, and it has nothing with `?.` operator which is applied to `this`.

*) I mean, your current code is equivalent to:

```
set
{
    _CurrentPage = value;
    PropertyChangedFire();
    if(this!=null)
        this.PageChanged(this,value);
}
```

while to invoke the event properly, you need:

```
set
{
    _CurrentPage = value;
    PropertyChangedFire();
    if(this.PageChanged!=null)
        this.PageChanged(this,value);
}
```

or rather, to be thread safe:

```
set
{
    _CurrentPage = value;
    PropertyChangedFire();
    var localref = this.PageChanged;
    if(localref!=null)
        localref(this,value);
}
```

Comment: While your code is correct, `?.Invoke` is a much shorter (and easier to understand) way of making a delegate thread safe.

Comment: sure, but: (1) there was no need to duplicate what Jonesopolis said (2) Jonesopolis actually did not explain **what/why** happened and this bits show it well (3) the code I provided is well-known ("traditional") and must be used everywhere below C# 6 (2+3) old style code explains the thing very well

Comment: Agreed, except the question was about using the null conditional operator... Your answer doesn't use the null conditional operator.

Answer (score 13):

You need to check if `PageChanged` is null.  Then you can call `Invoke` on it to raise the event.

```
PageChanged?.Invoke(this,value);
```

Side Note: this is exactly what Resharper recommends for C# 6